# How to remember form inputs without submit event when page is reloaded or refreshed?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, zend-framework

i am having form with many text inputs in a page

along with them i am providing zend pagination to select results.

but when i use zend paginate the user form inputs are lost as it is not submit

as the page reloads evertime i move to a new page is there any way i can maintain the user input .

Please can any one help me find a solution to this problem ..

Comment: Using sessions or cookies if the data is not sensitive. if you wanna save the info before the first "submit" then you would have to send the input's silently to php via ajax and manage them there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudo Code:

With javascript get the values on change and store it in a cooke (use jquery cookie plugin)

```
jQuery('form').on('change', 'input', function() {
    jQuery.cookie(...)
})
```

Comment: you code i am using to alert on paginate but dont know how to store form values in prefill them after chnage event .

Comment: Don't expect a full fledged application in this 'forum'. We give you hints and you investigate and try to programm. That way you will learn the most.

Comment: You have two possibilites: JavaScript or PHP

Comment: i want to use this approach along with yours as shown in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Xxqb6/2/ .

Comment: This looks good for a first timer. Now you have a second problem. Everybody can see the cookie values, as you store them directly in the  cookie as plain text. You need, as Ashwini said, an AJAX + Session solution. You do not send the data to the cookie but to a PHP file with AJAX. This PHP stores the data in the PHP session. A different PHP file will read the session values and send it back on AJAX request. All this should be with https

Answer (score 1):

And the solution is...

**AJAX** + **Session**

Send a ajax request on `change` event of every input.
Save data to `Session`.

Every time you load form data check for `Session` to fill form fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sessions:

```
$form = array();

if (!empty($_POST))
{
  $form = $_POST;
}

elseif (!empty($_SESSION['form']))
{
  $form = $_SESSION['form'];
}
```

And then use `$form` to populate the input fields.

Comment: The page has to be submitted the first time for the server to get the user's input; it's just that when using the pagination it's obviously not submitted (again) -- so you use the session to store that initial submit that is then reused when navigating the pages.

Comment: when i paginate nothing is sumitted it just like you open the page after filling the form you just hit reload or refresh . i checkked i dont get any values on post exit

Comment: zned pagination makes href link to page through records so its not a submit event

Comment: But presumably the user submitted the form to begin with? Else how would you have user input? You save that input in the session when they first submit the form and then re-use that session data when navigating the pagination.

Comment: actually user will sumit the form but he will loop through the results with pagination which is href url links only and that is where i am losing all input i was thinking of this approach  jsfiddle.net/Xxqb6/2  on chnage but its not working somehow

Comment: Yes, so when the user first submits the form put the input in the session. Then when navigating the pages use the data in that session.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ajax onfocusout of elements and store the value in the session.While loading the page fetch the data from the session and show it.

Comment: your idea sound usefull but i am noob in jquery